# How do I add a binary file to my existing PPA package

Tags: package-management, packaging

Adding modified or new text files to my PPA package is simple enough:

*Step 1:*

```
apt-get source [foo-package]
cd [foo-package]
```

*Step 2:*
add or modify new text files containing the changes

*Step 3 - update the changelog:*

```
dch -i
```

*Step 4 - create a patch*

```
dpkg-source --commit
```

*Step 5 - create a source package*

```
debuild -S
```

*Step 6 - upload to launchpad*

```
cd ..
dput [myppa]/[foo_source.changes]
```

---

However, I now need to add a new icon file (a .png file) to the existing package.

So at *step 2* - just copied into the [foo-package]

At *step 4* - I get the following errors:

```
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to foo-package/foo-icon.png: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
```

If I attempt to move to step 5 I get the following additional errors to the above:

```
dpkg-source: error: add foo-package/foo-icon.png in debian/source/include-binaries if you want to store the modified binary in the Debian tar-ball
...
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed
```

Any ideas how do I add a binary icon file to my existing PPA package?

---

More information

By running:

```
debuild -S --source-option=--include-binaries
```

This then allows for the source package to be built and *step 6* is possible.

However this isnt really the answer - because I subsequently cannot then make further code changes (*step 2*) because I'm still getting the same errors.

It doesnt look like I can do `dpkg-source --commit --source-option=--include-binaries` because this just gives errors:

```
dpkg-source --commit --source-option=--include-binaries
dpkg-source: warning: --source-option=--include-binaries is not a valid option for Dpkg::Source::Package::V3::quilt
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to foo-package/foo-icon.png: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I did:

```
apt-get source rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics
cd rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics-0.1/
echo '#Junk commit' >> llyrics/ChartlyricsParser.py
sed -i 's/Maintainer: fossfreedom <somewhere@xmail.com>/Maintainer: Andrew King (No comment) <newplace@ymail.com>/g' debian/control
sed -i 's/fossfreedom <somewhere@xmail.com>/Andrew King (No comment) <newplace@ymail.com>/g' debian/changelog
dpkg-source --commit

debuild -S -sa
mkdir debian/icons
cp ~/Pictures/awesome-cat.jpg ./debian/icons/
echo 'debian/icons/awesome-cat.jpg' > debian/source/include-binaries
cd ..
dpkg-source --include-binaries -b rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics-0.1
cd -
debuild -S

echo '#Junk commit' >> llyrics/ChartlyricsParser.py
dpkg-source --commit

#so now it's still allowing commits and in the deb-src...add it to install
echo 'debian/icons/* /usr/share/icons/hicolor/' >> debian/install
echo '' >> debian/install
debuild -S

#note that you should have the proper subfolders here e.g. 32x32/myicon.png or whatever
#also note that per packaging guidelines it should be one entry per file, not a wildcard
```

*Confirmed that it correctly pushes and builds on Launchpad* 
<sub>fossfreedom</sub>

Comment: Skeksi, bro! <fistbump>  Time to set those uuencoders straight? ;)

Answer (score 5):

#### Just get *dpkg-source --commit* to ignore binary files with the `extend-diff-ignore` switch

Here's another simpler way to do it: you basically tell *dpkg-source* to ignore what it can't comprehend (i.e., binary files), and to mind its own business ;)

After adding a binary file(s) the first time, the key is to use `dpkg-source --commit` with the `--extend-diff-ignore` switch, along with the appropriate paths/filenames to ignore (Perl regex format).

For example, suppose you stick a bunch of PNGs in the `llyrics` directory, and then you modify some text files. The correct commit call is:

```
dpkg-source --commit --extend-diff-ignore="(^|/)(llyrics/.*\.png)$"
```

Follow that with:

```
debuild -S --source-option=--include-binaries
```

to get your PPA upload.

---

Let's test this with the `rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics` package from fossfreedom's "playground" PPA:

1. Get source: `apt-get source rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics`
2. Modify a text file and add a PNG:

   ```
   $ cd rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics-0.1
   $ echo FORCE-A-DIFF >> llyrics/README 
   $ wget -Ollyrics/dancemonkeyboy.png \
      http://www.samrethsingh.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/untitled-image.png
   ... `llyrics/dancemonkeyboy.png' saved [243304/243304]
   ```
3. Add to changelog and increment version with `dch -v 0.1-3ubuntu6~izx1`
4. Commit text changes while ignoring the PNG with:

   ```
   $ dpkg-source --commit --extend-diff-ignore="(^|/)(llyrics/.*\.png)$"
   dpkg-source: info: local changes detected, the modified files are:
   rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics-0.1/llyrics/README
   Enter the desired patch name: PPABinaryTest
   dpkg-source: info: local changes have been recorded in a new patch: rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics-0.1/debian/patches/PPABinaryTest
   ```
5. Build source/changes:

   ```
   $ debuild -S --source-option=--include-binaries
   ...
   dpkg-source: info: building rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics using existing ./rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics_0.1.orig.tar.gz
   dpkg-source: info: adding llyrics/dancemonkeyboy.png to debian/source/include-binaries
   ...
   ```

And...voila! ([Launchpad-built deb--note the ~200k size difference...](https://launchpad.net/~izx/+archive/sandbox2/+build/3667794/+files/rhythmbox-plugin-llyrics_0.1-3ubuntu6%7Eizx1_all.deb))

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit harder than just adding a file.

First, you would need to rebuild the .orig.tar.gz with the included binaries in the new source package, and likely would need to increment the software version (`package_1.0.0.orig.tar.gz` -> `package_1.0.1.orig.tar.gz` or something) both in the tar, and in the `debian/changelog`.

After modifying the orig.tar.gz with the new files (do NOT include debian/ files in the orig.tar.gz), you would then add a `debian/changelog` entry, changing the version to increment it as you did to the orig.tar.gz.

Then rebuild the source package (`debuild -S`), and upload the new source package to the PPA.  That new source package will overwrite the "older" one in the PPA.

---

From Chat:

```
@LordofTime ... wouldnt launchpad complain that its just received a different original source file


@fossfreedom not if you increment the version
new version, new source
@fossfreedom if you don't increment the version it'll explode
so you must increment the version
also, make individual debian packages for each release of ubuntu
and it'll not yell as much (it'll still enforce original version)
i.e.
"I am updating the NGINX PPA from 1.2.2 to 1.2.3. I need to get the 1.2.3 source, and work from that."
"I change the package, and the .orig.tar.gz, and upload the new package to Launchpad."
"If there are no build errors, then i'm done. If there is a build error, then I damned well better fix that error."
(then reupload with 1.2.3-2 or something)
but generally i do build testing in a staging repo
```

Comment: Maybe this answer would benefit by being edited to just "if you don't increment the version it'll explode"?

Comment: You can always propose an edit to the answer Jonas, and comment why you think the edit is useful and I and others might look at it and consider it.

Comment: Sadly I am unfamiliar with the Debian packaging system, so exactly why it blows up is beyond me. An edit made by myself would be painfully inadequate.