# How to Create Deb Files

Tags: application-development, scripts, packaging, debian-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

I have a group of BASH scripts, XML files, etc. The scripts require that some programs already be installed. How do I create a *.deb on Ubuntu that will make sure that dependencies are satisfied and put my scripts and files where they need to be?

Comment: You should probably give an example file structure and desired target directory.

Comment: I am not sure yet where I would like to place the scripts. As for file structure, I have scripts in ./ and the XML files (AIML files to be more specific) are in ./aiml. I also have ./logs and ./temp. Does this answer your question @AbrahamVanHelpsing?

Comment: What do you want to add as dependencies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating .deb-Packages With Checkinstall**

http://www.howtoforge.com/howto_linux_debian_deb_checkinstall

**Checkinstall** is a nice tool to create simple .deb-packages that you can use in your local network (e.g. if you have to install the same piece of software on multiple computers running Debian). It lets you compile and install software from the sources like before, but with the difference that you end up with a simple Debian package which also means that you can easily uninstall the software you just compiled by running dpkg -r!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with something like this:

```
:~/testing/yourapp/yourapp$ find ./
./
./logs
./temp
./somenondescriptscript.sh
./aiml
./aiml/xmloraiml.aiml
```

If you have binary files (icons and other) you can [hide them in the ./debian folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164621/how-do-i-add-a-binary-file-to-my-existing-ppa-package/165062#165062).

For now let's add a version number to yourapp and build the orig.tar.gz.

```
cd ..  
mv yourapp yourapp-0.1  
tar czfv yourapp_0.1.orig.tar.gz yourapp-0.1/  
cd yourapp-0.1  
mkdir debian
dch --create -v 0.1-1 --package yourapp
```

Finish your edits and save the changelog.

Dependencies:

*Waits for OP response...*

References:
[Debian packaging guide](http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging)
[Another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164621/how-do-i-add-a-binary-file-to-my-existing-ppa-package/165062#165062)